# jquery get ID from element with a property

Tags: jquery, properties, jquery-selectors

I have the value of a property that is the only different in each of the elements:

property: and value example:
data-date="2016-04-08"

i need change the background color of only this but i dont knoe if jquery can do.

example current element on my html:

```
<td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-past" data-date="2016-04-08"></td>
<td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-past" data-date="2016-04-09"></td>
<td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-past" data-date="2016-04-10"></td>
```

i am looking the way to change the color background of it but i have only the property value as reference:

```
Earray[i] = "2016-04-08"
```

i am try with:

```
to get id : var idf = $(this).attr("data-date",Earray[i]).id();
```

change directly the CSS:

```
$(this).attr("data-date",Earray[i]).css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
```

but i no have a event over this element to get it with "this"
can help me with the selector or a element on my web page with a property "data-date" with a value like this: 2016-04-08

Comment: `$('[data-date=2016-04-08]').css('background-color', 'white');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector to retrieve the element. Try this:

```
$('[data-date="' + Earray[i] + '"]').css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/nLz6v84u/)

Note that you can combine the attribute selector with a class or element to improve performance, eg. `$('td[data-date="..."]')`. Also note that you should look to put the styling rules in separate CSS stylesheets and only add/remove classes in your JS code.

Comment: have example with td $('td[data-date="..."]')